# How does steam lose energy in a steam machine

Tags: energy, pressure

Steam engines take advantage of the volume increase of water when turning from liquid to gas state, and the resulting pressure increase. That's simple

To be consistant with the energy conservation law, the water (solid and liquid) mass has to "lose" energy in some way to compensate the energy "produced" by the steam motor. If it only lost kinetic energy, to my (poor) understanding, it would keep its pressure capacity to "push" another turbine, leading to infinite energy production.

So what does it lose? heat? To the point that it re-liquifies? How would that work at microscopic level?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of points about this: firstly, conservation of energy requires total energy to stay the same, not to be reduced. Secondly, in this case the water / steam does gain energy: it gets it from the "hot reservoir" in the system, e.g. the fire.

When gas expands to push a piston it loses both pressure and temperature. If you look at the 4 stages in an idealised version of a steam engine, the Carnot cycle, this corresponds to the first and second steps, where the engine does work on its surroundings. When it is then compressed again and ends up back in the cycle where it started, you find that in total some work has been done. This energy doesn't actually come from the gas though, it comes from the "hot reservoir" which is heated by your fuel.

Comment: What are the mechanisms that make the steam mass lose temperature? Is it directly linked to the pressure?

Comment: Imagine you've got a box full of gas, and one side is a piston. If you wait and allow the piston to be pushed out by the pressure of the gas, what happens is that each particle hitting the piston imparts a little bit of energy to it, losing energy itself.

Comment: Overall then, it's obvious that the pressure goes down since there are now the same number of particles spread over a greater volume. However the effect I mentioned above also causes the temperature to drop, since each particle that pushed the piston lost some energy, making the average energy of all the particles lower.